# Numeric layout not sticky in secure UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

My iOS6-targeted app has both normal and secure UITextFields.  In all cases, the following settings are used:

- Capitalization: None
- Correction: No
- Keyboard: Default
- Appearance: Default

The normal fields behave as I'd expect when I tap the "@123" key and a digit on the keyboard; the numeric layout remains until I tap the "ABC" key.  (In other words, I can type multiple digits in a row.)

The secure fields have a different behavior.  As soon as I type a digit, the keyboard immediately reverts to the default.  (In other words, I can't type multiple digits in a row.)

I've looked at many other apps with secure password fields, and I can't find any other case where the secure text fields reverts to the default layout as soon as a digit is typed.  Does anyone know what determines this behavior?

Comment: Try changing to some other keyboard Type. Never heard of this issue before.

Comment: I use this feature myself, but "default" for me is always ASCII, so I think the number pad coming out at all is the actual glitch.  Why not choose numbers & punctuation?  That's what I do...

Comment: @ACB me neither; keyboard type "ASCII Capable" has the same behavior, on Simulator and an iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, mea culpa.  The problem was caused by calling UITextField#reloadInputViews on the secure text fields.